# Reverse engineering an aircon controller. Need help figuring out a checksum

Tags: reverse-engineering, baud-rate

So I have been reverse engineering my aircon controller from around 2001, It uses a baud rate of 300 and sends the same packet of 6 bytes 3 times per transmission.

the data seems straightforward, however i cannot figure out how the last byte is calculated. Im almost certain its a checksum. Here is the data:

```
Fan level 2     0xFF    0xAA    0x00    0x02    0x68    0x0C
Fan level 3     0xFF    0xAA    0x00    0x03    0x68    0x67
Fan level 4     0xFF    0xAA    0x00    0x04    0x68    0x39
Fan level 5     0xFF    0xAA    0x00    0x05    0x68    0x52
Fan level 6     0xFF    0xAA    0x00    0x06    0x68    0x2A
Fan level 7     0xFF    0xAA    0x00    0x07    0x68    0x41
Fan level 8     0xFF    0xAA    0x00    0x08    0x68    0x53
Fan level 9     0xFF    0xAA    0x00    0x09    0x68    0x38
Fan level 9     0xFF    0xAA    0x00    0x49    0x68    0x03 (Turned Vent mode on)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely not a checksum. Notice that all bytes in all fan levels in your example are exactly the same, other than the 4th byte, which seems to be a combination of the index of the fan (lower nibble) and some flags indicating the status of that fan level (you can see that flag 0x4 is enabled when the vent on is enabled in fan 9).

Therefore, among all fan levels, the only change is only one byte, and in all lines in your example, but the last one, the value changes by an increment of one (the index of the fan level itself).

Therefore, if the last byte was a checksum, you would expect the checksums to be incremental values in the first lines of your example, but they are not.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I agree its nothing as simple as a checksum, however I do believe it could be some kind of error correcting code. I had a look into CRC but nothing seems to match...

Comment: Hi. Correct. It might be a proprietary check code. A while ago I found a remote that was using a byte of the previous "check" code plus an operation of the payload of the current message. In such case it becomes tricky to reverse engineer. you need to analyze very long sequences of messages to observe patterns. Just out of curiosity, what happens if you send the same message several times? What happens if you send fan level 1-9 and then level 9-1?

Comment: I looked into this, The same code is transmitted each time, as in: The error checking code does not depend on the previous message sent. If i cant figure it out, I might just record them all and make a lookup table.